# How do i get the iOS deployed version number from app-store using ionic3

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, app-store

I have already have an ios app deployed in App Store, say the version number of it is **1.0.3**. Which has been done using ionic 3 .

Now i need to fetch the latest version which is deployed (i.e 1.0.3) .

How i can do it programatically . So that i can get the app version and store it in a variable so that for the next deployment in can increase the version number as
**1.0.4.**

Is there any kind of plugin available to get it.

As i have searched in ionic framework, there is an [App-Update](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/app-update/) plugin which only works for android.

Is there any similar plugin to get the already installed app's version number?

Comment: Use This Plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-version

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have used;

```
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version';
constructor(private appVersion: AppVersion) {}

this.appVersion.getVersionCode().then((res:any) => {
  console.log('app version', res);
});
```